# LINQ contains not creating a like statement

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

It's been a while since I've used Entity Frameworks and LINQ. I am attempting to perform an SQL like query. This works fine in a one to many relationship defined via a foreign key in the parent table.

```
myEntity.Where(me => me.relatedEntity.Name.Contains("a");
```

This correctly translates to a like in SQL. However when I query a many to many relationship via a junction table it creates an equals statement in SQL.

```
var name = "bo";
myEntity.Where(me => me.Users.Select(u => u.Name).Contains(name));
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: The 2nd version you are checking if any entity in the collection of names 'contains' the name which is indeed an equal. You should use `me.Users.Any(u => u.Name.Contains(name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, in your first query the source is an string and the second one the source is a collection of strings. I think what you are looking for is this:

```
var r=myEntity.Where(me => me.Users.Any(u => u.Name.Contains(name)));
```

If you want as condition that all the users contain some string pattern then use `All` extension method instead `Any`.